# Is "remaining sum" the same as "remaining balance"

Tags: finance

What's the term to express "left money in my account" ? I found BALANCE, REMAINING SUM and REMAINING BALANCE. Are they identical? Thanks!

Comment: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/sum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When speaking of a bank account, one normally uses 'balance', but everyone would perfectly understand what you meant if you said 'sum' or 'amount', which in this sense are synonyms.

When talking about the notes in your wallet and coin in your purse or pocket, however, one wouldn't use 'balance'. The usual term would be 'amount'.

Answer (score -1):

Source: My own experience in American English (IN, KY, TN, FL)

"Balance" and "Remaining Balance" are common and familiar to me. "Remaining Sum" is odd because "Sum" is the result of addition, and the statement you're trying to make implies subtraction. If there was addition involved, we'd probably say "resulting balance." or "new balance".

Comment: I beg to differ; certainly in BrE (which I have spoken in several of your US states as well as in Br) the term *sum of money* is entirely comprehensible and very commonly used to mean an amount, whether that amount be arrived at by addition, subtraction, multiplication or indeed theft.

Comment: *Sum* can mean "amount," in fact, that's the primary meaning according to http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/sum

Comment: I can't argue with the comments above about the actual meaning of "sum", but the rest of my answer, I believe, holds true.