# Word for calculating/adjusting a payment when I previously paid too much?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

As part of a [percentage rent](https://www.propertymetrics.com/blog/2014/01/16/percentage-rent/#), I need to pay my landlord 10% of my monthly revenue, but no lower than $10,000.

Therefore, I automatically pay $10,000 at the beginning of each month. So let's say we're dealing with January. I pay $10,000, and shortly into February, I have determined my monthly revenue, and 10% of it is $15,000. Now I need to pay an additional $5,000 for January, *instead* of all 10% of my revenue (because I already put down $10,000).

Now, what is the word for what we did to the 10% of revenue to use only the portion needed to leave the landlord with only $15,000?

Example sentence:

> Because I have already paid $10,000, we must _________ the $15,000.

The word *[offset](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/offset)* has been suggested, but I do not think it is an accurate choice.

Also - please make suggestions that fit in the example sentence above, the structure is quite important to my question.

Comment: "For January's rent we owe $15,000, less the $10,000 we have already paid."

Comment: Because I have already paid $10,000, we must _pay the difference to make up_ the $15,000.

Comment: Because I have already paid $10,000, we must pay the residual of $5000 on the total of $15,000.

Comment: _please make suggestions that fit in the example sentence above, the structure is quite important to my question._ This is a great example of someone [trying to fit a square peg in a round hole](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/square+peg+in+a+round+hole).

Answer (score 5):

You ***deduct*** the advance payment ($10,000 in this case) from the final/total rent payable.

> Because I have already paid $10,000, we must ***deduct*** it from the
>   total ($15,000).

ODO:

> **[deduct](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/deduct)**
>   *VERB*
>
> [WITH OBJECT] Subtract or take away (an amount or part) from a total:
>   ‘tax has been deducted from the payments’
>
> ‘Any severance already paid to the workers will be deducted from that
>   amount, the judge ruled.’

TFD(idioms):

> **[deduct (something) from (something else)](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/deduct+from)**
>   to subtract an amount from another amount.
>   Mr. Wilson deducted the discount from the bill.
>
> McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs. © 2002 by
>   The McGraw-Hill Companies, Inc.

Wiktionary:

> *Verb*
>   **[deduct](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deduct)** (*third-person singular simple present* deducts, *present participle* deducting, *simple past and past participle* deducted)
>   To
>   take one thing from another; remove from; make smaller by some amount.
>   I will deduct the cost of the can of peas from the money I owe you.

Answer (score 3):

... we must pay the [balance](http://www.investorwords.com/390/balance.html).

See also [this entry](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/189118/is-remaining-sum-the-same-as-remaining-balance).

Answer (score 3):

*Offset* is fine, but you don't offset the $15000. You offset the $10k against that sum.

> Because I have already paid $10,000, we must offset it against the $15,000.

[Oxford's](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/offset) definition isn't particularly helpful, but there is an example which matches, noting how tax liability can be reduced by charitable donations already made:

> **offset** *verb*
>   *[with object]* Counteract (something) by having an equal and opposite force or effect:
>
> > ‘donations to charities can be offset against tax’

Other examples, showing a slightly different usage:

> - The cost would be roughly $1.5 billion, which he says would be offset with spending cuts. [[online.wsj.com](http://online.wsj.com/article/SB10001424052748703399204574505521056936130.html?mod=sphere_ts&mod=sphere_wd)]
> - The cost of the program was partly offset with a $1 million grant from Mercury Insurance. [[dailynews.com](http://www.dailynews.com/politics/ci_9007817)]

In both usages, *offset against* and *offset with,* the larger sum is as stated and the smaller sum is offset.

Comment: It seems to me that was is being counteracted here is the $15k - according the the rules, I need to pay the 10% which is 15,000. The $10,000 I have already paid counteract that amount.

Comment: As I said, the Oxford **definition** is not very helpful. Their **example** shows it in use, in a situation which is analogous to yours. A sum already paid is *offset against* a sum due.

Comment: Thanks for you answers. I find it hard to get a clear understanding by skipping the definition and using the example (i've seen this definition in other dictionaries also, and it really seems to be what I suggested), which is why I'm reluctant to award you the bounty. Can you back this up further?

Comment: Alternatively, couldn't we offset the 15k with the 10k? See here for some examples: http://fraze.it/n_search.jsp?q=offset+with&l=0&t=0&ffo=false&findid=-1&ff=

Comment: You can use *offset with,* but it's still the smaller sum which is offset.

Comment: Sorry, but I beg to differ - The cost of the program (large and unstated) is being offset. It is being (partly) offset by the small sum of $1m...Also, we don't know what "spending cuts" amount to, but it seems like the spending cuts don't reach $1.5 billion because otherwise the spending cuts would subsidize (or other similar word) and not just offset.

Comment: No, it's not. It is the small cost which is offset against the big cost. The big cost is reduced by having the small cost offset against it. *Or,* the big cost is offset with the small cost. It's still the small cost doing the offsetting.

Answer (score 2):

The *[overage](https://www.realestateagent.com/real-estate-glossary/real-estate/overage.html)* is exactly the term for the additional increment of rent that you must pay:

> **overage**, **1**: Rental increment tied to sales or profit that is in addition to the flat rental fee. Assume a retail store in a mall is
>   charged a base rental of $5,000 per month plus 2% of sales. If sales
>   are $100,000, the overage would be $2,000 and total rental would be
>   $7,000.

So, for your hypothetical month of February, your overage is $5,000, your total rental is $15,000, from which you *[debit](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/debit)* the $10,000 base rental already paid.

To fit your sentence:

> Because I have already paid $10,000, we must *debit it* from the
>   $15,000.

To fit more common usage, the sentence should use the form *be debited* somehow:

> Because I already paid my base rent, $10,000 should *be debited* from
>   this month's rent of $15,000.

Comment: It might well be, and it's not the point, Gnawme. That's not what was asked

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin If you read the _entire_ answer, I filled in the blank of the sentence the OP wanted completed.

Comment: Thanks Gnawme and while that looks fine in ordinary English two things.

1) We're not talking about ordinary English, but a rather specialised vocabulary where a mistake could cost the poor guy a lot of money

2) You didn't fill in the sentence. You changed it for another, even though the poor guy had specifically stressed: 'Also - please make suggestions that fit in the example sentence above, the structure is quite important to my question.'

Comment: This is a useful answer, thanks for the new word! However, it doesn't actually fit my needs.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin - I'm writing a user guide for a software that has this functionality, and trying to find the appropriate words to describe it, so don't worry, no one will lose a lot of money. I'll be sure to describe everything well enough that even if the terminology isn't perfect, people will understand what they're doing.
P.S. I'm not a poor guy, really doing fine :)

Comment: Uh… thanks for the clarification. Do you realise there's no faint clue to the guide in the question?

It's still sad that trying to make suggestions fit in the example sentence above is spoiling the whole idea. The structure is very important and it's also quite clearly the largest part of the problem.

If it's for a software guide, what words does the software itself use, for goodness sake? How might original manual have explained the example you gave?

Answer (score -1):

"Because I have already paid $10,000, we must **now settle the arrearage of** the $15,000."

**arrearage**:

something that is in arrears; especially :  something unpaid and overdue.
(Merriam-Webster)

Answer (score -2):

Because I have already paid $10,000, we must **remit** the amount from the $15,000.

https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/remit

"If you’ve been in prison for five years of a seven-year sentence but you’ve been on good behavior, a judge might remit the remainder of your sentence and let you go free."

"release from (claims, debts, or taxes) “The taxes were remitted” Type of: cancel, strike down declare null and void; make ineffective"

Comment: This many downvotes with no explanation? Can someone enlighten me as to why the word is not appropriate for this post?